# groovy activemq thread consumer example

Tags: multithreading, groovy, activemq-classic

I want to have a groovy script that will consume messages from an ActiveMQ queue until a condition is met (not message related).

The intention is that this script will be used in testing a messaging system and will be doing something along the lines of the following pseudo-code:

```
start_listening_for_messages()
call_REST_API_to_create_messages()
stop_listening_for_messages()
check_received_messages()
```

I am using the following as a starting point:

```
/* groovy -cp activemq-all-5.3-SNAPSHOT.jar */

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import java.lang.InterruptedException
import javax.jms.*

server = 'activemq-server.test.com'
queue = 'messagequeue'

ConnectionFactory jms = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL: "tcp://$server:61616");

Connection connection = null
Session session = null
Destination destination = null
MessageConsumer consumer = null
Message message = null
TextMessage textMessage = null

looping = true

try {
    connection = jms.createConnection()
    connection.start()
    println connection

    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    println session

    destination = session.createQueue(queue)

    consumer = session.createConsumer(destination)

    println "listening for message from $queue..."
    while(looping) {
        message = consumer.receive();
        println "message received!"

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            textMessage = (TextMessage) message
            println textMessage.getText()
            looping = false
        }
    }
    println "closing session"
    session.close()
    println "closing connection"
    connection.close()

} catch (InterruptedException e) { 
    println "catch InterruptedException"
    println e.getMessage()

} catch (JMSException e) {
    println "catch JMSException"
    println e.getMessage()

} catch (Exception e) {
    println "catch Exception"
    println e.getMessage()
} finally {
    try {
        if (consumer != null) {
            consumer.close()
        }
        if (session != null) {
            session.close()
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close()
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println "finally catch Exception"
        println e.getMessage()
        return
    }
}

println "done"
```

I am trying to use a separate thread for the consumer:

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import java.lang.InterruptedException
import javax.jms.*

server = 'activemq-server.test.com'
queue = 'messagequeue'

def t = Thread.start {
    ConnectionFactory jms = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL: "tcp://$server:61616");

    Connection connection = null
    Session session = null
    Destination destination = null
    MessageConsumer consumer = null
    Message message = null
    TextMessage textMessage = null

    looping = true
    try {
        connection = jms.createConnection()
        connection.start()
        println connection

        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        println session

        destination = session.createQueue(queue)

        consumer = session.createConsumer(destination)

        println "listening for messages from $queue..."
        while(looping) {
            try {
                message = consumer.receive();
                println "messages received!"

                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    textMessage = (TextMessage) message
                    println textMessage.getText()
                    // array.append(textMessage)
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) { 
                println "loop catch JMSException"
                println e.getMessage()

                looping = false
            }
        }
        println "closing session"
        session.close()
        println "closing connection"
        connection.close()

    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
        println "catch InterruptedException"
        println e.getMessage()

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        println "catch JMSException"
        println e.getMessage()

    } catch (Exception e) {
        println "catch Exception"
        println e.getMessage()
    } finally {
        try {
            if (consumer != null) {
                consumer.close()
            }
            if (session != null) {
                session.close()
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close()
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            println "finally catch Exception"
            println e.getMessage()
            return
        }
    }
}


def i = System.console().readLine 'Waiting for newline'

println "interrupt"
t.interrupt()

println "join"
t.join()

// print array of messages here

println "done"
```

The 'readLine 'Waiting for enter' is a place holder where other methods will be called (HTTP/REST API call that creates messages).

When I attempt to use threading/interrupt/join, after hitting the enter key, exceptions are generated and the process does not complete; it hangs until Ctrl-C/interrupted:

```
C:\dev\groovy\>groovy -cp activemq-all-5.3-SNAPSHOT.jar messagelistener.groovy
Waiting for keypressActiveMQConnection {id=ID:...}
ActiveMQSession {id=ID:...}
listening for messages from messagequeue...
messages received!
{"message":"test"}

interrupt
join
loop catch JMSException
java.lang.InterruptedException
closing session
catch JMSException
java.io.InterruptedIOException
Oct 24, 2014 6:38:20 PM org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer dispose
INFO: Failed to send remove command: javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.InterruptedIOException
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.InterruptedIOException
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1216)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.asyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1208)
        at org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer.dispose(AdvisoryConsumer.java:56)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:599)
        at javax.jms.Connection$close$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at eventlistener$_run_closure1.doCall(eventlistener.groovy:82)
        at eventlistener$_run_closure1.doCall(eventlistener.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:98)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.oneway(ResponseCorrelator.java:60)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1214)
        ... 21 more

finally catch Exception
java.io.InterruptedIOException
done
```

-hangs-

What changes need to be done to have the script run and complete in expected behavior/without exceptions/stacktrace/errors?

Comment: I'm no Java threading expert, but using it in a Groovy script is likely fraught with peril. I'd suggest looking at using GPars for this. It should be easier than using Java threads directly.

Comment: Here is Groovy's docs on concurrency where there is example code using thread and join: [Concurrency with Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Concurrency+with+Groovy) - why would this be fraught with peril?